# QT opengl заполнение окна сеткой

Tags: qt, opengl

Прикрепил код по выводу сетки на екран. Но сетка по заданному шагу не доводит 1 итерацию внизу и справа. Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы сетка доводила по низу и по правому краю по 1 итерации?

```
введите сюда код
void a::_draw_play() {
auto aw = a::width();
auto ah = a::height();
int N=aw/10;
int M=ah/10;
P p[N][M];
for(int x=0;x<N;++x)
  {
    for(int y=0;y<M;++y)
      {
        p[x][y].x=x*aw/N;
        p[x][y].y=y*ah/M;
      }
  }

   glViewport(0, 0, (GLint)aw, (GLint)ah);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, aw, ah, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLineWidth(1);

  for(int x=0;x<N;++x)
{
  glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
  for(int y=0;y<M;++y)

      glVertex2i(p[x][y].x,p[x][y].y);
  glEnd();

}

 for(int y=0;y<M;++y)
{
  glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
  for(int x=0;x<N;++x)

      glVertex2i(p[x][y].x,p[x][y].y);
  glEnd();

 }

}
```

Comment: Решил данный вопрос!
auto aw = a::width()+10;
auto ah = a::height()+10;
....
glOrtho(0, aw, 0, ah, 0, 1);

Comment: исходники https://github.com/richkirl/snake